# Postgres - monitoring the startup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to start up a postgres 9.5 database on a windows machine.

I click on the start menu, select 'PostgreSQL' then I click on 'Start PostgreSQL 9.5' and run it as administrator.

I can see that the shortcut is linked to...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\sc.exe start "PostgreSQL 9.5 Server" -D "D:/PostgreSQL/data/pg95"
```

How can I check/monitor what's happening when I run this?

I've tried opening a windows command prompt (as administrator) and pasting the above line, this is what I see....

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\WINDOWS\system32\sc.exe start "PostgreSQL 9.5 Server" -D "D:/PostgreSQL/data/pg95"

SERVICE_NAME: PostgreSQL 9.5 Server
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 8524
        FLAGS              :

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I then visit task manager to look for a process ID of 8524 but there's no sign of any such PID.

How can I diagnose what's gone wrong and why the service hasn't started?

From the windows side I've checked the event viewer, but can't find any mention of *ANY* events at the moment I attempt to start the service (although could be just because I haven't worked out how to use the event viewer correctly)

From the postGres perspective, I've done a search for all files that end with *.log and checked the file date - none of the logs have been modified at a time close the time I attempted to start the service.

Where can I check to see what's happening? The postgres service definitely hasn't started, but non of the postgres logs have anything in them and the windows event viewer isn't revealing anything either.

This post related to a previous one ([Postgres shared memory errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766049/postgres-shared-memory-errors) )

UPDATE
I have checked postgresql.conf, and found a number of log files in log_directory, but none of them have a timestamp as recent as my attempts to re-start the database. I have also checked the contents of the log files and none of them show any messages from the time of the start up. I have also checked for all files in the postgresql home that end with .log -none of them show any sign of recent changes either.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log, there you can see what is going on and why it couldn't start.

Comment: @Laurenz - which log and where to find it please? Postgres seems to have lots of log files but non of the ones I can find have been changed.

Comment: In `postgresql.conf`, examine `log_destination`, `logging collector`, `log_directory` and `log_filename`, then you should be able to find out where the log is written.

Comment: And until you fix the problem you might need to update the postgresql.conf to log all messages as per below without the "#". You need to restart postgresql to enable the log changes, by running services.msc

    #log_min_duration_statement = -1 # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
    log_min_duration_statement = 0